# can`t open storyboard on stable version Xcode

Tags: storyboard, xcode10, xcode11

I made a mistake by opening my project in a new beta version of xcode

Now I can not open it with a stable version because

```
The document “Main.storyboard” requires at least Xcode 11.0.
This version does not support iOS 13.0 system colors. Open this document with at least Xcode 11.0.
```

On Saturday, I planned to publish the application.
and it can not be published with the beta versions.

I need to run the application on the standard version of xcode

Is there any way to fix my situation?

Comment: Obviously you could restore a backup or an older version, if you did a backup or use something like git? If not, you could try to open your project in Xcode beta, open your storyboard file and select the file inspector in the inspectors view on the right hand side. There is an option "Interface Builder Document" > "Opens In", try to change this from Xcode 11 to Xcode 10. Check if there are any new errors like for example if you use the new system colors mentioned in your error message. Hopefully afterwards it will work in Xcode 10 again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> The document “Main.storyboard” requires at least Xcode 11.0. This
>   version does not support iOS 13.0 system colors. Open this document
>   with at least Xcode 11.0.

solved

open the storyboard as source code and first delete the lines:

```
<capability name = "iOS 13.0 system colors" minToolsVersion = "11.0" />
```

and everything where there is

```
cocoaTouchSystemColor
```

And then in the Interface builder to restore the desired colors.

thnx for Russian Stack Overflow
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/992148/322338

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to delete this line:

```
<capability name="collection view cell content view" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
```

And then replace all appearances of **collectionViewCellContentView** with **view**.